# Avoiding vertical shift when using \foreach to display a series of images

Tags: beamer, graphics, foreach, loops, only

I'm trying to show a sequence of almost identical images in a beamer frame, to be able to step back and forth and compare the differences. The images are numbered as `image1.pdf`, `image2.pdf` etc., and it seemed practical to present them using a `\foreach`-loop.

To my surprise this seems to cause some, not all, of the images to be vertically shifted! I've boiled it down to the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]<1>{./figs/image1}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]<2>{./figs/image2}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]<3>{./figs/image3}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \foreach \number in {1,2,3}{
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]<\number>{./figs/image\number}
    }
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \foreach \number in {1,2,3}{
      \only<\number>{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./figs/image\number}}
    }
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first frame behaves as I intended, and all images are placed in the same spot.

In the second frame, *all but the last two* images are higher than the rest. This happens for any number of images: most are aligned but I get a shift near the end.

In the third frame, *all but the very last* image are shifted upwards.

As I want to compare differences between the similar images the shift is very annoying, and for now I have to go with the first construction. I have some long series though, and it would be nice to be able to avoid writing all the file names out explicitly.

**Is there any way to display a series of images using a loop, which does not cause some of the images to be shifted?**

Comment: you probably need `%` and ends of lines and perhaps `\mbox{}` before the `\only` but don't use `\number` as your loop variable, that is the TeX primitive for accessing the decimal value of a counter and locally redefining will break large amounts of code